# Where does AndroidStudio find gradle?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I am building a Project using AndroidStudio (Dolphin 2021.3.1). Under the Project tab, I see "Gradle Scripts"->"build.gradle". I haven't installed Gradle. How does that script run? Is it built in to AndroidStudio?